# java milliseconds find closest to current time

Tags: java

I have following code:

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    diff[i] = a.getTime() - b.getTime();
}

a.getTime() = time in array.
b.getTime() = current time on computer.
```

What would be the best way to find which one of a.getTime is nearest to current time?

Output diff:

```
-143214521
32942394
-132931
-21340
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep the *absolute* value of the difference (using `Math.abs`), and keep track of the minimum value you've seen so far, along with the index at which it occurred.

For example:

```
long currentTime = b.getTime(); // Only call once, to be consistent
long minAbsDiff = Long.MAX_VALUE;
int minIndex = -1;
for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    diff[i] = a[i].getTime() - currentTime;
    long abs = Math.abs(diff[i]);
    if (abs < minAbsDiff) {
        minAbsDiff = abs;
        minIndex = i;
    }
}
```

This is assuming you still need `diff[i]` elsewhere. If you don't, and if you only need the `a` value with the minimum difference, you can write it more compactly:

```
long currentTime = b.getTime(); // Only call once, to be consistent
long minAbsDiff = Long.MAX_VALUE;
WhateverType minContainer = null;
for (WhateverType x : a) {
    long abs = Math.abs(x.getTime() - currentTime);
    if (abs < minAbsDiff) {
        minAbsDiff = abs;
        minContainer = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sigh. Your answer is beautiful (+1). But at least I spotted a typo. :-) it's `Long.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: @S.P.Floyd - seanizer: Doh! Fixed, thanks. Had my mind half in C# ;)

Comment: and now you've fixed half of the typos :-)

Comment: @S.P.Floyd - seanizer: Gah! Done :)

Answer (score 1):

Do [`Math.abs(long)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28long%29) on each of the results and use the lowest one.

(Create an array of type `long[]`, put the abs() values inside and then sort it using `Arrays.sort()`)

BTW, you probably want to do `b.getTime()` only once.

Comment: Moreover you may get rid of the `long[]` array and just keep track of the lowest value you've calculated so far.

Comment: sure, but my way is probably easier for a beginner.

Comment: Or you could create a list of type `Long` and use `Collections.min`.

Comment: Sure, that's more usable, but also more memory consuming. Why create objects if primitive operations are all you need?

Answer (score 1):

```
long min = Long.MAX_VALUE;
long current = b.getTime();
int index = -1;
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
   long diff = Math.abs(current - a.getTime());
   if(diff < min) {
     min = diff;
     index = i;
   }
}
```